# Submit form when a file is uploaded using ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax

I want to submit a form to upload a file. The problem I have is that I need to use AJAX to send the temp path to php and then get an array as response.

Basically, I want to submit the form, get the temp path, send it to PHP using JS and then from PHP return an array as response to JS

this is what I have so far:

```
<form name="form1" id="frmXML" method="post" action="">
<div>
    <label for='upload'>Agregar XML:</label>
    <input id='upload' name="upload[]" type="file" accept=".xml" multiple="multiple" onchange="doSelect(this)"/>
</div>
```

JS:

```
function doSelect(el){

    $.ajax({
        type : 'POST',
        data: {
                path:this.document.getElementById('upload').value,
                submit: 'submit',
              }
        url : 'Logica/Usuario.php',
        dataType:'json',
        success : function(response){

            var len =response.length;

            if(len>0)
            {
                //Do something              
            }
        }
    });
    return false;

  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't.

Leaving all the logistics of mixing Ajax and non-Ajax aside, this is what would happen:

1. The form would send the file to PHP
2. The PHP would run, assign the file a temporary path, generate a response, delete the file from the temporary path, and exit
3. The JavaScript would get a file path that no longer existed
4. The JavaScript would make an Ajax request to the other PHP and send it a file path
5. The other PHP would look at that file path and not find the file, because it has already been deleted

---

If you want to do Ajax and relate a file to it, then the simplest approach would be to just make a **single** HTTP request, using Ajax, and include the file in it.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to submit the form after the ajax request completed, so this should work :

```
if(len>0)
    {
        $('form').submit()              
    }
```

Comment: No, I want to submit the form, get the temp path, send it to PHP using JS and then from PHP return an array as response to JS